# Helm doesn't find kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

Tags: kubernetes, google-api, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm, v3.4.1:

```
user:~$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.1", GitCommit:"c4e74854886b2efe3321e185578e6db9be0a6e29", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.11"}
```

I cannot seem to add https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com repo
(which is very clearly available, if you follow the link)

I am executing command:

```
user:~$ helm repo add google https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Error: repo "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is no longer available; try "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" instead
```

and getting following error:

```
Error: repo "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is no longer available; try "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" instead
```

How to solve it?

Comment: what is your opposition to doing what the message says and switching to charts.helm.sh?

Comment: @mdaniel the fact the current project setup expects me not to? Talked to the person responsible for writing the readme and according to them, "it shouldn't do that". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, up to you but [they laid out the deprecation timeline](https://helm.sh/blog/charts-repo-deprecation/) and it has a [dedicated FAQ](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#when-i-add-a-helm-repo-i-get-the-error-error-repo-httpskubernetes-chartsstoragegoogleapiscom-is-no-longer-available) so it seems like trying to work around it is not putting yourself on a path to success

Answer (score 3):

They have put new location for the stable repository and for the incubator repository.  Along with the new locations, Helm v2.17.0 and v3.4.0 have been released to help you use the new location.

**stable**

```
old location - https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

new location - https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

**incubator**

```
old location - https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com

new location - https://charts.helm.sh/incubator
```

Read more: [stable-incubator-charts](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/).

As I can see you have helm version v3.4.1 which is released on November 11, 2020 contains only bug fixes from v3.4.0 which means that it also has changed location for stable repository.

Solution is to simply execute command:

```
$ helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```